# Uploading nested Data into firebase with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload several levels of nested data into firebase from my iOS application, I am struggling with nesting part as I have only used dictionaries to upload the data, is it possible to upload nested data using several levels of nested dictionaries? I'm just not quite sure how to go about this problem. This is what I've started out trying, I'm not sure what direction to go In regarding the nesting:

```
func uploadSession(uid: String, session: Workout){

        var data = [String:Any]()
        var sets = [String:Any]()
        var modifiers = [String:Any]()

        for exercise in session.exercises {
            for set in exercise.setsObject! {

            }
        }

        REF_SESSIONS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["userName" : CurrentUser.instance.userName as Any, "userID" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as Any, "start time" : session.startTime as Any, "end time" : session.endTime as Any, "notes" : session.notes!, "session RPE" : session.sessionRPE!, "exercises" : ""])
    }
```

[image: table structure example]

Comment: If you pass a `Dictionary` for any of the values that you pass into `updateChildValues`, the database should write the entries of that dictionary as nested values. Is that not working for you?

Comment: the problem is I need an arbitrary amount of dictionaries inside the dictionaries

Comment: That too should work. Firebase will simply treat every dictionary as a nested object, including dictionaries in dictionaries in dictionaries, etc. Can you show what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I got it to work, but for the key I used a counter, so instead of it being random keys its just listed from 1-x

Comment: If you want the same keys that Firebase uses, you can generate one by calling `REF_SESSIONS.childByAutoId().key`. This won't create anything in the database, just gives you a new unique key.